# AngularJS: Assign class to dom element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have a DIV that I want to set it's class based on a calculation:

View.HTML

```
<div ng-class="SetClass(item)" ></div>
```

Controller.js

This is a scope function:

```
$scope.SetClass = function(item) {
    if (item.Date between date1 and date2)
         return 'status-class-1';
    else if (item.Date between date3 and date4)
         return 'status-class-2';
    else
         return 'status-class-3';
}
```

This works fine but I noticed if I add a console.log('function called') inside this function then this function gets called hundreds of times just when scrolling the screen which is the correct AngularJS behavior for the $digest.loop

Is there a way to assign a class to function that's dependent on some calculations without this performance hit ? I don't want to add a lot of conditions directly into my VIEW as there could be far more than these 3 conditions.

Comment: This is how Angular works. You probably shouldn't be running digest loops on scroll if you're concerned about performance... if you need to update something on scroll, it's probably best to just manipulate the DOM directly on scroll events.

Comment: I do think there is an issue around the `$digest` loop running on scroll, I'm assuming you have another piece of code that is causing this, but that sounds expensive and probably isn't ideal. As for the class itself, a better option may be to add a new "class" property to the item itself on your server and calculate the class while building your view model, this way you won't have any logic in the angularjs controller/view, and it will minimize the work angular is doing.

Comment: @Tyler I was hoping for an angularjs 'best practice' solution but doing it on the backend works so it's an option

Comment: @MikeD Is the item.Date changing on the UI? If not, there is no reason to calculate that in the client side code. A good use case of `ng-class` would be if you were letting them pick a date and wanted to change the class based on what they picked, but if you are just displaying a static date and want to style it different depending on the value, it would make more sense to calculate that on the server.

Comment: @Tyler I make a query to the backend every 10 minutes and those dates get updated, I need to set a status class based on those dates that's why I'm doing it this way, I'm thinking of just making this calculation on the backend

Comment: @MikeD For this use case I do think the back end makes more sense. Otherwise, the way you have it set up is perfectly fine and would be considered best practice as far as the way it is set up. The issue is something not posted above, but rather what ever is causing your $digest loop to run on scroll. That is not best practice and will probably become a larger problem if you add more data or logic to your page.